# convert AT&T to Intel in osx

Tags: assembly, nasm, intel, gnu-assembler, att

I want convert this code block to intel

```
xorps  %xmm0, %xmm0
movaps %xmm0, -64(%rbp)
movb   $2, -63(%rbp)
movl   $3103850762, -60(%rbp)
movw   $20480, -62(%rbp)
leaq   -64(%rbp), %r14
```

how I can do it?

Edit:

I write this :

```
xor  r15,r15
mov  [rbp-64] ,r15
mov  [rbp-63] ,2  ; ***** line 21
mov  [rbp-60] ,3103850762
mov  [rbp-62] ,20480
lea  r13,[rbp-64]
```

but it's not work , error is :

```
sok.asm:21: error: operation size not specified
sok.asm:22: error: operation size not specified
sok.asm:23: error: operation size not specified
```

Comment: It's about AT&T syntax and Intel syntax, not gas & nasm

Comment: ok , what is Intel syntax for it?

Comment: AT&T synxtax reverses all arguments compared to Intel syntax. Besides Intel syntax doesn't use prefix and instruction suffix. There are lots of documents about this that you can get with only a simple google search http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~kslarsen/dm546/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax Questions lack of research may be deleted without reason

Comment: I search it before , but I had one 3 error ,  Edit , my question , and insert my error

Comment: You need `mov qword ptr [rbp-63], 2`. Without it the assembler cannot know what size you need to move since there's no instruction suffix in Intel syntax. And xmm0 is not r15 too. A quick note: comma should go with the previous word, not the next one

Comment: nasm doesn't use `ptr`. In nasm syntax it would just be `mov qword [rbp-63],2` (but since the original instruction was `movb` it should probably be translated into `mov byte [rbp-63],2`).